# Beehive Simulation: A counter of a type of bee returns unusually high numbers

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I am constructing a simulation of beehive and I make use of a 2D array called **workerBee**.
It has the following 6 fields: beeId, Age, Type(egg = 1, larva = 2, pupa = 3, worker = 4, drone = 5), PollenCollection, Eaten, Alive

Brief about the model: The Queen Bee lays eggs daily(10 to 50 eggs) and they are added to the hive.Each day, data about the bees are updated(their age and type).

For every day that passes, I print the beehive status which prints information about the number of bees, births, deaths etc..
For some days during the simulation(at the beginning, say day 6 to 10), the number of larva reported is around 800 to 900 for 1 day.
Here are the codes that deal with the printing and counting:

```
    public static int layDailyEggs() {
        Random randomEggs = new Random();
        final int MAX_EGGS = 50;
        final int MIN_EGGS = 10;

        int x = randomEggs.nextInt((MAX_EGGS - MIN_EGGS) + 1) + MIN_EGGS;
        eggsLaid = x;//eggsLaid as a global variable to be used in printBeehiveStatus
        return x;//To pass as argument to addEggToHive
}
    public static void addEggToHive(int eggsLaid) {
        //Update the workerBee array with available slots
        //Traverse the 2D array and while beeId != 0, add eggs and update
        for (int i = 0; i < workerBee.length; i++) {

            if (workerBee[i][0] == 0 && eggsLaid > 0) {
                //Available space           
                workerBee[i][0] = i;//Update beeID
                workerBee[i][1] = 1;//Update age
                workerBee[i][2] = 1;//Update Type
                eggsLaid--;
        }
    }
}
    public static void countTypesOfBees() {
        //Initialize for each day
        totalEggsLaid = 0;
        numberOfBirths = 0;
        numberOfLarva = 0;
        numberOfPupa = 0;
        numberOfWorkerBees = 0;
        numberOfDrones = 0;

        //To call upon updating type of each bee
        for (int i = 0; i < workerBee.length; i++) {

            if(workerBee[i][2] == 1) {
                totalEggsLaid++;
            }else if(workerBee[i][2] == 2) {
                numberOfLarva++;
                numberOfBirths++;
            }else if(workerBee[i][2] == 3) {
                numberOfPupa++;
                numberOfBirths++;
            }else if(workerBee[i][2] == 4) {
                numberOfWorkerBees++;
                numberOfBirths++;
            }else if(workerBee[i][2] == 5) {
                numberOfDrones++;
                numberOfBirths++;
            }
        }
}
    //Method called once daily
    public static void metamorphose() {     
        numberOfDeaths = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < workerBee.length; i++) {

            //Updating the type of bee based on age of Bee
            if(workerBee[i][1] == 4) {
                workerBee[i][2] = 2;            
            }else if (workerBee[i][1] == 10) {  
                workerBee[i][2] = 3;
            }else if(workerBee[i][1] == 20){
                //Probability for a drone to emerge is 10%(As per area under curve, should be less than or equal to 10%)
                double probability = random.nextDouble();
                if (probability <= 0.1) {   
                    workerBee[i][2] = 5;//Drone Bee
                }else{
                    workerBee[i][2] = 4;//Worker Bee        
            }
        }
        if (workerBee[i][1] == 35 || workerBee[i][1] == 56) {
            //Call a funeral
            funeral(i);
            numberOfDeaths++;
        }

    }
    countTypesOfBees();     
}
    //To be called at the end of the day
    public static void printBeehiveStatus() {

        System.out.print("Queen laid " + eggsLaid + " eggs!" + 
                         "\nBeehive status\nEgg Count: "+ totalEggsLaid + "\nLarva Count: " + numberOfLarva + "\nPupa Count: " + numberOfPupa +
                         "\nWorker Count: "+ numberOfWorkerBees + "\nDrone Count: " + numberOfDrones + 
                         "\nDeath Count: " + numberOfDeaths + "\nBirth Count: "+ numberOfBirths +
                         "\nHoney Stock: " + honeyStock +"\n");
        printFlowerGarden();
}
```

The index of the fields of the **workerBee** array are in the order specified above. 
The order which which they are executed each day are as follows(Note that they are not the complete set)

```
    addEggToHive(layDailyEggs());
    incrementAge();
    metamorphose();
    printBeehiveStatus();
```

Screenshot  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTeuo.png
Screenshot  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMsHq.png

Note
**The eggs hatches into larva when it is 4 days old**
If there is anything else that you think might be causing the problem, tell me I'll upload that part of the code.

Comment: Java is an Object Oriented language. I suggest to try to abstract your task with classes and objects instead of 2D arrays of `int`. In its current state your code is hard to understand.

Comment: I understand, but this is a coursework. It requires modular programming only at the moment. I wish I could do so and I know it's possible. But I have to meet the requirements of the coursework.

Comment: Well, in that case, I suspect you have a problem with your static variables. For example, you have a `eggsLaid` static variable, and in some methods you have a local variable of the same name. That can lead to issues - if you are not updating the variable that you think you are updating. If you must using static variables, at least don't give them the same names as your local variables.

Comment: I tried changing it, still nothing changed.

Comment: Please use an [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @shaw even if you cannot use a struct instead of an array, creating helper functions like `isEgg(workerBee[i])`, `layEgg(workerBee(i))` and `metamorphose(workerBee[i])` would do wonders for readability. Also calling `new Random` every method call is not useful, and making all functions `static` limits reusability.

Comment: @KenY-N Thanks for the reply, what do you suggest I do to make my functions more readable then?And why calling Random is not useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. 
Actually, the method incrementAge() was supposed to increase the ages of all bees in the hive by 1 each day. However, I was simply incrementing **all** ages in the array without checking whether that particular row is an **actual bee or not as I had initialized unused rows to 0**